# Progress indicator in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have created some basic applications using windows forms C#.

What I am trying to achieve is that I have  some task taking place inside a function. While executing that task I need to display a message box (with no buttons) with the text "Configuring...". I also need to blink this text. How can I do that?

Do I need to have another form for this? After completing this task this form needs to be hidden or closed?

I have googled this but couldn't see an answer, may be because of my unclear question in google.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a progress indicator you have to do as toATwork said, and do a Background worker
However, it is not a really async task, so you might find it hard to make it work properly

If you finally don't care about the message, and just need to show the users that something is happening, you can always use:

```
// To start
Cursor cursor = Cursor.Current;
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

// To finish
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

This will just put the mouse cursor in "loading", but it might work for you

Answer (score -1):

You can use a label on your form and change its text in function Body.

```
{
//your function body
label.Text="Configuring";
}
```

Comment: But how to blink that text?

Comment: When you will run you program text will be changing at run time text will seem to blink.... I think

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/655c8e33-f2a0-4033-8873-0032ac757019/create-blink-text-effect?forum=winforms   check this

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436491/How-to-show-label-in-blinking-style   it will make text blink of a label